# How does torch.argmax work for 4-dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I am a newbie in Pytorch. Even though I read the documentation, it is unclear for me how does torch.argmax() applied to first dimension work when we have 4-dimensional input. Also, how does *keepdims=True* change the output?

Here is an example of each case:

```
k = torch.rand(2, 3, 4, 4)
print(k):

tensor([[[[0.2912, 0.4818, 0.1123, 0.3196],
          [0.6606, 0.1547, 0.0368, 0.9475],
          [0.4753, 0.7428, 0.5931, 0.3615],
          [0.6729, 0.7069, 0.1569, 0.3086]],

         [[0.6603, 0.7777, 0.3546, 0.2850],
          [0.3681, 0.5295, 0.8812, 0.6093],
          [0.9165, 0.2842, 0.0260, 0.1768],
          [0.9371, 0.9889, 0.6936, 0.7018]],

         [[0.5880, 0.0349, 0.0419, 0.3913],
          [0.5884, 0.9408, 0.1707, 0.1893],
          [0.3260, 0.4410, 0.6369, 0.7331],
          [0.9448, 0.7130, 0.3914, 0.2775]]],


        [[[0.9433, 0.8610, 0.9936, 0.1314],
          [0.8627, 0.3103, 0.3066, 0.3547],
          [0.3396, 0.1892, 0.0385, 0.5542],
          [0.4943, 0.0256, 0.7875, 0.5562]],

         [[0.2338, 0.2498, 0.4749, 0.2520],
          [0.4405, 0.1605, 0.6219, 0.8955],
          [0.2326, 0.1816, 0.5032, 0.8732],
          [0.2089, 0.6131, 0.1898, 0.0517]],

         [[0.1472, 0.8059, 0.6958, 0.9047],
          [0.6403, 0.2875, 0.5746, 0.5908],
          [0.8668, 0.4602, 0.8224, 0.9307],
          [0.2077, 0.5665, 0.8671, 0.4365]]]])

argmax = torch.argmax(k, axis=1)
print(argmax):
tensor([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
         [0, 2, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 2, 2],
         [2, 1, 1, 1]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2, 2],
         [0, 1, 2, 0]]])


argmax = torch.argmax(k, axis=1, keepdims=True)
print(argmax):
tensor([[[[1, 1, 1, 2],
          [0, 2, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 2, 2],
          [2, 1, 1, 1]]],


        [[[0, 0, 0, 2],
          [0, 0, 1, 1],
          [2, 2, 2, 2],
          [0, 1, 2, 0]]]])
```

Comment: Which PyTorch version are you using? The API has changed from axis to dim a while ago...

Comment: Can't you tell by looking a the shapes, and the indices?  Start with a smaller  example if it helps.  And axis=1 is the second dimension

Comment: I am using 1.6.0+cu101, it also works with dim

Comment: I understand how it works with 2, 3 dimensions but 4 dimensions made me confused

Comment: @tugcegurbuz wow, thought it was removed, but it does work =] btw, `dim=1` is the second dimension, not the first. Just to be clear, what exactly is confusing you? The shapes with and without `keepdim=True` are different...

Comment: @Berriel Firstly, in my example, argmax returns (2, 4, 4) because I applied it to the first dimension. If it is returning the highest value across the given dimension, why it gives (4, 4)? I tried to find what does each value in (4, 4) part means (i.e., is it max row, max column index) by checking maximum values at each dimension but looks not consistent.  Secondly, how does keepdim=True change the shape?

Comment: @tugcegurbuz Original shape: `(2, 3, 4, 4)`. `argmax` with `dim=1` should give you `(2,4,4)` (`dim=1` is the 2nd dimension), and it does. If you set `keepdim=True`, then it will keep the original dimensions, putting a 1 on the `dim` you selected, therefore returning `(2, 1, 4, 4)`

Comment: @Berriel keepdims part is clear for me now, thank you so much! But still couldn't understand whether the indices that argmax returns reflect max column or max row in the given dimension

Comment: @Berriel oh just solved it on my own! No need to answer, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `k` is a tensor of shape `(2, 3, 4, 4)`, by definition, `torch.argmax` with `axis=1` should give you an output of shape `(2, 4, 4)`. To understand why this happens, you have to understand what happens in lower dimensions first.

If I have a 2D (2, 2) tensor A, like:

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4]]
```

Then `torch.argmax(A, axis=1)` gives the output of shape (2) with values (1, 1). The axis argument means *axis along which to operate*. So setting `axis=1` means that it will look at values from each column one by one, before deciding a max. For row 0, it looks at column values 1, 2 and decides that 2 (at index 1) is the max. For row 1, it looks at column vales 3, 4 and decides that 4 (at index 1) is the max. So the argmax result is [1, 1].

Moving up to 3D, let's have a hypothetical array of dimensions (I, J, K). If we call argmax with axis = 1, we can break it down to the following:

```
I, J, K = 3, 4, 5
A = torch.rand(I, J, K)
out = torch.zeros((I, K), dtype=torch.int32)

for i in range(I):
    for k in range(K):
        out[i,k] = torch.argmax(A[i,:,k])
        
print(out)
print(torch.argmax(A, axis=1))

Out:
tensor([[3, 3, 2, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 3, 3]], dtype=torch.int32)
tensor([[3, 3, 2, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 3, 3]])
```

So what happens is, in your 3D tensor, you're once again calculating argmax along the columns/axis 1. So for each unique pair of (i, k), you have exactly J values along the axis 1, right? The index of the maximum value within those J values is inserted into position (i,k) of the output.

If you understand this, then you can understand what happens in 4D. For any 4D tensor of dimensions (I, J, K, L), if you call argmax with axis=1, then for each combination of (i, k, l) you'll have exactly J values along axis 1 - and the argmax of those J values will be present at output[i,k,l].

The `keepdims` argument is merely conserving the number of dimensions of your matrix. For example, argmax at axis 1 on the 4D matrix gives a 3D result of shape (I,K,L), but using keepdims, the result will be 4D as well with the shape (I,1,K,L).

Answer (score 0):

Argmax gives the index corresponding to highest value across a given dimension. so the number of dimensions is not an issue. so when you apply argmax across the given dimension, PyTorch by default collapses that dimension since its values are replaced by a single index. Now if you don't want to remove that dimension and instead keep it as one, then you could use `keepdims=True`.

Comment: In my example, argmax returns (2, 4, 4) because I applied it to the first dimension. If it is returning the highest value across the given dimension, why it give (4, 4) in this case? I tried to find what does each value in (4, 4) part means (i.e., is it max row, max column index) by checking maximum values at each dimension but looks not consistent.

Comment: it is returning index of the highest value for each element in the other dimensions. therefore the result should have the same dimensions as the other remaining dimensions

Comment: can you explain in more detail it is not clear still